# How to remove first n character of multiple file names in mac

Tags: python

I want to rename multiple files to that the first 9 characters are deleted.
example:

**Before:**

```
19.49.29 1

19.50.17 2

19.50.24 3

19.50.28 4

.

.
```

**After that:**

```
1

2

3

4

.

.
```

I tried using python but it screwed up my files and the orders:

```
import os

folderPath = r'/Users/**myusername**/Desktop/FOLDER'
fileNumber = 1

for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    os.rename(folderPath + '//' + filename, folderPath + '/' + str(fileNumber) + '.jpeg')
    fileNumber +=1
```

maybe there's a way using terminal or anything else?

Comment: does it relate to bash?

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh` (which the OP included as a tag)

```
% autoload zmv
% zmv '* (*)' '$1'
```

This will treat each filename as a space-separated pair of words, and use the second word as the new name for each file.

If you really need the condition to be "drop the first nine characters", then

```
% zmv '?????????(*)' '$1'
```

Comment: ok, how do i make it so it will only target a selected folder?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to use `cd` to change the working directory first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using python3, you can simply use the slicing feature of strings (as they're all arrays) and just keep the 9 leftmost characters like this:

```
filename = "12.23.34 1.jpeg"
print(filename[9:])
```

This will start at the 9th character(1) and spit out the rest so you would have "1.jpeg". So in your code, if we assume that ALL your images are 10 characters long (eg: "12.23.34 1.jpeg") the line you had:

```
os.rename(folderPath + '//' + filename, folderPath + '/' + str(fileNumber) + '.jpeg')
```

can be changed to:

```
os.rename(folderPath + '//' + filename, folderPath + '/' + filename[9:])
```

Comment: ok, this worked for a few files, but not all. a bit strange..

Comment: Might be that not all of your files are the exact same length in the beginning (e.g. some are correct->12-12-12 1.jpeg  and some are not->12.431.12.3 1.jpeg. Could you provide a screenshot of the files in the directory?